# Logo Design Does Not Meet Standards

Tags: logo, typography, critique

So I recently started working for a company (I am a software engineer) and due to emergency situations, I had to cookup a company logo from a jpeg file the company had. What I made and the company had are pretty similar and presented below:

[image]

Please realise that I am no professional graphic designer, yet even to me, this logo feels, well odd. Is there any ratio, design tips, ideas etc. to make this logo more pleasing to the eye? What Have I (and the previous designer) got wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two symbols in your logo but they fall into the background because the color values are pretty close. If you darken the yellow to an orange it will give you more contrast from the background. The font could be a lot stronger, right now it's reading like a title instead of a logo. Based on the name of your company the graduation cap is probably the most important symbol. You should make that large and recognizable.

This is a great [analysis](https://www.getty.edu/education/teachers/building_lessons/principles_design.pdf) on the principles of design.

**Before**

[image: Logo Before]

**After**

[image: Logo After]

Comment: Brilliant! May I ask which font should I use? Thanks!

Comment: @Jeet.Deir I used Oswald from Google Fonts for my mock up but they have a huge library to choose from. I'd recommend something sans serif. I liked the all caps look with the font I used but you may want to change that depending on what you pick. https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Oswald